# How to remove first dimension in multidimension array

Tags: php

How to remove first dimension in **multidimension** array

```
array(
    [0] => array(
               [0]->1
               [1]->2
           )
)
```

Now echo

```
echo id[0][1];
```

how to get

```
echo id[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [*array_shift*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$new_array = array_shift($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit trivial. Putting answer in different format than original answer above to not hide logic of what needs to happen behind a function call (though other answer is totally valid).

```
$new_array = $old_array[0];
var_dump($new_array);
```